# ModelNotFoundError in Django

Tags: python, django, cs50, modulenotfounderror

For some reason, VS code doesn't recognize some standard external Django modules. I keep getting
the `ModelNotFoundError`. When I try to run pip or pip3 install on for example django.contrib I'm getting the following error:

`ERROR: No matching distribution found for django.contrib`

I'm using VS Code on Windows 10.
Would be awesome if someone could help me fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

To install **Django** run

```
pip install Django
```

To install for **Python3** run

```
pip3 install Django
```

If you want to use the latest version run

```
pip3 install Django --upgrade
```

Once Django is installed you should be able to import `contrib` in your **Python** or **Python3**:

```
import django.contrib
```

So `contrib` is just a module within the larger Django project that you have to install before being able to import it.

Answer (score 0):

django.contrib does not need to be installed separately. It is included with django.

You just need to add it to to the INSTALLED_APPS.

See docs:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/